# How to remove contextmenu items from gecko webbrowser control,"i want to disable view source in browser"

Tags: c#, geckofx

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_ShowContextMenu(object sender, GeckoContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ContextMenu.GetContextMenu().MenuItems.RemoveAt("view in system )
     {

     }                
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_ShowContextMenu(object sender, GeckoContextMenuEventArgs e)
  {      
   foreach(MenuItem i in e.ContextMenu.MenuItems)      
   {
     if(i.Text == "View in System Browser")
        e.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Remove(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks ,i just wrote I in caps,"View In System Browser" and it starts work for me